# Returning the address of a vector element C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-address

I have 2 classes, one is called A, the other B.

In class B there is a vector of elements of type A. Let's call it vectorofAs.

I am writing a function in B that returns a pointer to A, and this A is an element of the vector.

Here is the function

```
A* B::function() const {
 *do something to find the needed element index i*
 return &vectorofAs[i];
}
```

Shouldn't this return the adress of the ith element of the vector?
Intellisense says "Error: return value type does not match the function type"

Comment: What's the type of `vectorofAs` and `A` ?

Comment: Show us how "vectorofAs" is really defined and how you use it.

Comment: Aside from the `const`, there's a very unlikely second possibility, that `A` might overload unary `operator&`. In that rare situation (or in generic code for which you don't know anything about the type `A`), the way to get the real address of the object is `std::addressof`, or `boost::addressof` if you don't have C++11.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify, but I'm assuming: `vectorOfAs` is defined as a member of class B with the type `std::vector<A>` .

In that case, the issue is that your `function` is defined `const`, which means that all members of the instance of `B` are also const inside this function.  That means that your `vectorOfAs` is a `const std::vector<A>`.  That means that the type of `&vectorOfAs[i]` is `A const *` not `A *` as your function is returning.

You have two options:

1. Change the function return type to `A const *`
2. Make the function non-const.

Answer (score 0):

You have marked the function as const.

So `this` is a `const B*`, vectorofAs becomes a `const vector<A>`, and `vectorofAs[i]` is `const A&` and `&vectorofAs[i]` is a `const A*` which is not the same as an `A*`

So either put a const in front or remove the one at the end

Comment: Thank you very much, I removed the const and it worked.
I'm new to C++, I'm not sure what's the difference between const in the beginning and const in the end anymore. I thought const in the end is used to tell the compiler that the function won't change anything to the class members?

Comment: Yes, but when you return a normal pointer to an A, someone can use the pointer to change that A.

Comment: @jazzybazz: `const` after a member function signature indicates that the function can be called via a `const B &` or a `const B*`. It's unwise to modify non-`mutable` members in that function, and the compiler will take some steps to persuade you not to modify them, but it is *not* a promise to the compiler that you won't do so.